# Nginx auth basic not working with rewrite

Tags: nginx, rewrite, http-basic-authentication

I need to protect one directory with the basic auth and rewrite all urls inside this directory only.

I have the following config:

```
    location /admin/ {
            auth_basic "Secure area";
            auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;
            rewrite  ^(.*)$ /admin/index.php last; break;
    }
```

However, basic auth not working. If I comment `rewrite` rule it starts working.

How to fix it?

Comment: Does it work the way you want to if you remove the `auth_basic` and `auth_basic_user_file` directives?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, yes, it works.

Answer (score 2):

"rewrite" goes before basic auth, because of request workflow.

try trick with error page and named location:

```
 location /admin/ {
            auth_basic "Secure area";
            auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;
            error_page 404 = @admin;
    }

location @admin {
            rewrite  ^(.*)$ /admin/index.php last;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, it works partly. Basic auth works, but the rewrite rule does not. After logging, if I try to refresh the page it redirects me back to admin/index.php instead of staying on the dynamic page. If I remove your code, it works exactly as it is supposed to.